# Zsh super slow inside my Git repo

Tags: macos, zsh, oh-my-zsh

My Zsh is super slow inside a certain Git repo of mine. When I Google "zsh git slow", I get a bunch of results about Git *autocompletion* being slow, but autocompletion isn't necessarily my problem; it's *everything*.

I tried removing all plugins and that, strangely, didn't do anything at all when I opened a new shell. Zsh would still do Git stuff inside my Git repo.

I found this snippet on [this page](http://marc-abramowitz.com/archives/2012/04/10/fix-for-oh-my-zsh-git-svn-prompt-slowness/):

```
function git_prompt_info() {
  ref=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD 2> /dev/null) || return
  echo "$ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_PREFIX${ref#refs/heads/}$ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_SUFFIX"
}
```

That made everything fast again, but it also gave me a prompt that looks like this:

```
➜  snip git:(master
```

Note the missing right parenthesis. That's kind of lame. Plus the whole thing just seems like a hack I shouldn't have to do.

There's also this promising-looking SU question, but the links on the accepted answer are dead.

**How can I get my Zsh not to be slow inside a Git repo?**

Comment: Can you link us to the SU question you mention?

Comment: Also, What did you have in your prompt when things were slow (before your snippet)?

Answer (score 5):

You can execute following command to totally disable git status feature.

```
git config --global oh-my-zsh.hide-status 1
```

Or adding the following line into your `~/.zshrc`.

```
DISABLE_UNTRACKED_FILES_DIRTY="true"
```

Answer (score 4):

To trace the shell commands which are invoked while it is slow, you can run: `set -x` or add into your startup files. It will show you all commands, including the one responsible for autocompletion.

If you believe some `git` commands are slow you may define some extra variables such as:

```
exports GIT_TRACE=1
```

To see more examples, see: [How can I debug git/git-shell related problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6178401/55075)

Comment: should we do `exports GIT_TRACE=0`?

Answer (score 2):

I have removed `zsh-autosuggestions` as a plugin and then it was faster. In my case it had nothing to do with `git`.

Comment: -1 removing plugins obviously makes loading faster

Answer (score 1):

It's not that autocompletion is slow, it's that autocompletion makes every command seem slow because you are waiting for it to source stuff. Trying commenting out bash_completion completely in your zsh dot files.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything relevant there to comment out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try confirming the source of your slowness with `zprof`. Add this to your `~/.zshrc` (or equivalent):

```
zmodload zsh/zprof
```

then run `zprof` after each command to get a summary. In my case, it was a totally unrelated plugin that was causing the slowness.